# detect when subview showed up on screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios6

Have 2 functions, function 1 download data (photos and names) and when download is complete I call function 2 to update screen with that data (showing up buttons thumbnails with the photos and names).

I'm starting an `ActivityIndicator` in function 1, and then removing it later at end of function 2.

The problem is after run both functions (and consequently removing `ActivityIndicator`) app still takes some seconds processing data till it finally is able to show it on screen.

Wonder if there's any way to detect that a subView (buttons thumbnails in my case) have showed up on screen. Something like `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` methods when adding a `subView`.

Comment: damn, I forgot my crystal ball at the office. There-for I am not able to see your code. sorry.

Comment: Are you doing everything on the main thread?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't post any code or my question wasn't completely understandable..didn't do it cause it's too much code..yes I'm using blocks either to download data and update screen, although they are in separate methods. Anyway just wanted to know if there's any event that could be detected as soon as subView is loaded. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try incorporating a block (i am making some assumptions since you didn't post code):

```
//start activity indicator
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Call function 1

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Call function 2
        // hide your activity indicator
    });
});
```